# Vue.js input element values are empty

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My JS fiddle of the issue is here:

https://jsfiddle.net/taslar/krcfx4u5/9/

```
<div id="app">
  <h1>
    This should not print.
  </h1>
  <div id="pickList">
    <h2>Todos:</h2>
    <ol>
      <li v-for="todo in todos">
        <label>
        <input type="checkbox"
          v-on:change="toggle(todo)"
          v-bind:checked="todo.done">
        <del v-if="todo.done">
          {{ todo.text }}
        </del>
        <span v-else>
          {{ todo.text }}
        </span>
        <input v-model="todo.notes" />
      </label>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <button @click="print">print</button>
</div>


new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    todos: [
      { text: "Learn JavaScript", done: false, notes: 'What is JavaScript' },
      { text: "Learn Vue", done: false, notes: 'Doing' },
      { text: "Play around in JSFiddle", done: true, notes: 'Done' },
      { text: "Build something awesome", done: true, notes: '' }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function(todo){
        todo.done = !todo.done
    },
print() {
      var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=600,width=800');
      printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Print This</title>');
      printWindow.document.title = 'printthis.pdf';
      printWindow.document.write('</head><body >');
      printWindow.document.write('<div class="container">');
      var pageElement = this.$el.querySelector('#pickList');
      var html = pageElement.outerHTML;
      printWindow.document.write(html);
      printWindow.document.write('<br />');
      printWindow.document.write('<br />');
      printWindow.document.write('</div>');
      printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
      printWindow.document.close();
      printWindow.print();
    }
}
})
```

The behavior I was hoping for was:

When the print button is hit the model values for the input elements would also be in the pick list.

This feels like is "should work", but the input elements are empty when I hit the print button.

I don't understand what mark-up I need to get Vue.js to write the model values on the input elements to the printWindow document.

**Update (for those finding this through the internet):**

Handling textarea tags was a simple matter of setting the v-html attribute.

Select tags I handled with this bit of code:

```
        var selectElements = Array.prototype.slice.call(pageElement.querySelectorAll('select'));
        selectElements.forEach(function (el) {
            for (var index = 0; index < el.options.length; index++) {
                option = el.options[index];
                if (option.value === el.value) {
                    option.setAttribute('selected', true);
                    return;
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: pass your `todo.note` as html value attribute, `<input v-model="todo.notes" value="todo.notes" />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because when you're copying the elements, you actually do not copy their state (e.g. `value` of the text input, or the `checked` property of the checkbox). So what you need to do is to iterate through all input elements in the `pageElement` node, and assign the stored values as HTML attributes instead:

```
var pageElement = this.$el.querySelector('#pickList');
var inputElements = Array.prototype.slice.call(pageElement.querySelectorAll('input'));
inputElements.forEach(function(el) {
    if (el.type === 'text')
        el.setAttribute('value', el.value);

    if (el.type === 'checkbox' && el.checked)
        el.setAttribute('checked', '');
});
```

See your fixed fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/1h6e4n7z/

---

This also implies that you will need to update the logic above, if you have other input types, for example, `<select>` will need to be handled separately, and so is `<textarea>`.

Answer (score 0):

pass you `todo.note` as value attribute in your HTML tag. 
e.g: 
`<input v-model="todo.notes" value="todo.notes" />`

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  That didn't work completely for me because (in my actual solution) the view model is updated via an API call so when the view is generated the inputs are empty.  It did work for the components within the printable area, though.